# Angular 2 Material: same height for MdCards

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Angular2, Material2 and Bootstrap.
Layout is basically

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <md-card></md-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <md-card></md-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <md-card></md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

All cards have different content, hence different height.

How can I make them of same height? (flexboxes.. but how?)

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/eTMewPHAj0RsgWYPZgWd/)

NB: I'm using Bootstrap for responsive grid, since Material2 still doesn't have its layout system. Any solid grid system will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, this CSS seems to have worked for me:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row md-card,
.row md-card .md-card {
  height: 100%;
}

.row md-card .md-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row md-card .md-card md-card-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wah0Ykdd0AkHnDZZs0Vb?p=preview)

If a better answer is posted I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class **.row-eq-height** to each card. That uses the flexbox CSS3 property, so if you don't like adding that class, it's the same as doing:

```
.col-md-4 {
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple :) please try flexing with plunker link above